# Sublime C++ define from settings

Tags: c++, macros, sublimetext2, c-preprocessor

I'm using sublime editor and want such things for programming competitions (TopCoder):
when testing locally, I want to read from file, but when sending, I want code to read from console. Now, I do it like this: I have 2 lines:

```
freopen("A.in", "r", stdin);
freopen("A.out", "w", stdout);
```

which I comment prior sending. Is there anything like define something from IDE, and then used #ifdef to decide if I'm compiling locally or sending?

Answer (score 2):

Make up your own symbol. e.g.

```
#ifdef JANI_LOCAL
    freopen("A.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("A.out", "w", stdout);
#endif
```

When you compile it locally define the symbol on the command line (assuming g++ compiler):

```
g++ -DJANI_LOCAL source.cpp
```

The code between the `#ifdef`/`#endif` will be compiled locally but will be ignored when compiled by the judging software.

Comment: where can I change that command line arguments which sublime uses to call g++? where can I add JANILOCAL